# How to save the data into database in jquery and display upon the screen using web api

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to add the values inot the database but I am not to able to do that.

```
        var Array;
         $(document).ready(function ()
            {
         $.ajax({
             url: '../api/Emp/GetAll',
              type: 'Get',
                     cache: false,
                     datatype: 'json',

                     success: function (text) {

                            Array = text.Table;
                            var List = JSON.stringify(text);

                               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var Id = Array[i].id;
            var Name =Array[i].name;
            var city = Array[i].city;

                  $('#table body').append('<tr><td>' + Id + '</td><td><input           type="text" value="' + Name + '" id="txt' + Id + '" /></td><td>' + city + '</td>    </tr>');              
          }
     }
 })
```

Comment: Could you add your php code? Also check the console and see if you are getting an error.

Comment: Could you also check if you put closing brackets around your document ready function.

Comment: m using web api asp.net,using post method m trying to do

Comment: i have data in it i m able to display the data using Get method now my requirement is like i wann edit the data and edited one should be stored into the db.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put it back into the database you just need to reverse the process.

Use **post** for your type and send the data back with ajax to a php script page that inserts the data into your database.

You can edit the data on the php page before you insert it into the database or you can edit the data with javascript then send it back to php page.

Create an ajax post

```
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   datatype: "json",
   url: "insertPage.php",
   data: {dataNameHere: editedDataGoesHere},
   success: function(data){
     alert("SUCCESS");
   },
   error: function(e){
     alert("ERROR");
   }
});
```

And then in your PHP:

```
$obj = $_POST['dataNameHere'];
```

and insert it into your database like you normally would.